# Using a GUID In The Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

For some reason I'm unable to use comparisons on GUID columns, it does not return any results.

See below, with the WHERE clause set to the exact value of the 'secguid' column, it does not return any results. What's going on?

```
SELECT * FROM dbMobileFile

SELECT * FROM dbMobileFile WHERE secguid = '3137459D-EFDE-449E-94A3-89345A8580FA'

SELECT * FROM dbMobileFile WHERE secguid LIKE '3137459D-EFDE-449E-94A3-89345A8580FA'
```

Using LIKE does not work either.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to TRIM secguid in Where clause

Comment: Please show your `LIKE` query. And try to use text in question (in addition to images)

Comment: Can you confirm the table definition? Especially, is `secguid` defined as `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: It's a nvarchar currently.

Comment: @W.H Try `LTRIM` and `RTRIM`. That should do the trick I guess

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM dbMobileFile WHERE secguid LIKE '%3137459D-EFDE-449E-94A3-89345A8580FA%'` (note the `%`s)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever changing the field to UI works, can you post an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Try running `select quotename(secguid,'''') from dbMobileFile`; to show any leading or trailing spaces.  Also, why are you using `nvarchar` rather than `uniqueidentifier` for this column (there may be good reasons to; but if there aren't you're best off using the most relevant type.

Comment: Old question, but refer to my answer below. Qualify the UniqueIdentifier with {}

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
SELECT      [fileID],
            [fileCOde],
            [filePassword],
            [fileDescription],
            [rowguid],
            [secguid]
FROM        [dbo].[dbMobileFile]
WHERE       CAST(secguid as uniqueidentifier) = CAST('3137459D-EFDE-449E-94A3-89345A8580FA' as uniqueidentifier)
```

Comment: `WHERE       secguid = CAST('3137459D-EFDE-449E-94A3-89345A8580FA' as uniqueidentifier)` works for me too

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention that the column is stored as `NVARCHAR`, its possible that the string has leading or trailing whitespaces, which is why it might not be popping up in the query with the `WHERE` clause.

You can try this :

```
SELECT      [fileID],
            [fileCOde],
            [filePassword],
            [fileDescription],
            [rowguid],
            [secguid]
FROM        [dbo].[dbMobileFile]
WHERE       LTRIM(RTRIM(secguid)) = '3137459D-EFDE-449E-94A3-89345A8580FA'
```

which should show you the result as leading and trailing whitespaces are eliminated in the `WHERE` clause.

Also, in case you want to make use of the `LIKE` operator, you can write your query as :

```
SELECT      [fileID],
            [fileCOde],
            [filePassword],
            [fileDescription],
            [rowguid],
            [secguid]
FROM        [dbo].[dbMobileFile]
WHERE       secguid LIKE '%3137459D-EFDE-449E-94A3-89345A8580FA%'
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Both those solutions would have terrible performance. The correct solution would of course be to change the  `secguid` column to actually be a guid.

Comment: @Magnus Agreed. That's the best solution. However, I did not know (at the time of answering) if the OP has the freedom for table modification (for example if its a live application with a edmx connection maintained by someone else). As far as the question was, how to get the result with the `WHERE` clause, this will do (though not the best solution which I am in complete agreement with).

Answer (score -1):

I've had this problem with a corrupt database. Some GUIDs be contained in the WHERE clause, with other GUIDS on the same table would not return results.

Turns out that database had Index issues. Run DBCC to make sure your database isn't corrupt.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer works, but it is a bit verbose and probably not the intended way to do this. UniqueIdentifier is qualified by {}, so the following is the easiest;

```
SELECT * FROM dbMobileFile WHERE secguid = '{3137459D-EFDE-449E-94A3-89345A8580FA}'
```

Answer (score -1):

See inside the database that guid value stored as 32 hex digits:00000000000000000000000000000000 so if we search by 32 hex digits separated by hyphens: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, it's not get any output

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbMobileFile WHERE secguid = ('3137459D-EFDE-449E-94A3-89345A8580FA')
```

Use parentheses to enclose GUID string LIKE `(`'GUID'`)`

Comment: Did not work. Use the "CAST" solution cited above instead.