# SQLServer: Search where on uniqueidentifier guid

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, jdbctemplate

How do I search for a unique identifier guid in SQLServer table, without doing table scans? Should I just use string or cast as uniqueidentifier? I see different examples on internet.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Product
where productGuid = '321F6C1D-3B28-4880-B1ED-434D7AE299D8'

SELECT * FROM dbo.Product
where productGuid = cast('321F6C1D-3B28-4880-B1ED-434D7AE299D8' as uniqueidentifier)
```

When doing text string search, I still saw seeks in execution plan. Should I cast as uniqueidentifier to be safe, since we are using Java and JDBCTemplate?

Comment: There's a nice article [Watch Out For Implicit Uniqueidentifier Conversions](https://improve.dk/watch-out-for-implicit-uniqueidentifier-conversions/) on this but things may have moved on in SQL 2019.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. SQL Server will implictly convert a properly formatted string constant to a uniqueidentifer and use indexes when appropriate.

Comment: @mattsmith5, , David beat me too it. Throw some points at him since he types faster than me ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Product
where productGuid = '321F6C1D-3B28-4880-B1ED-434D7AE299D8'
```

Is fine because UNIQUEIDENTIFIER has a higher [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) than VARCHAR.  So the VARCHAR literal is converted to a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and the index can be used.

The case you have to look out for is where the literal or parameter has a higher precedence than the table column, which causes all the column values to be converted to the literal or parameter type for comparison, and will (generally*) prevent index use.

*there are some special cases where the comparison avoids the column-side conversion.

Comment: interesting this person had issues, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42293740/15435022

Answer (score -1):

If using it in this format (GUID format), the correct way would be:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Product
WHERE productGuid = CAST('321F6C1D-3B28-4880-B1ED-434D7AE299D8' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFER)
```

Comment: please see other answers in the question, thanks